# LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: errors

While i wrote `\begin{document}`  but it gives me the error what should i do?

You can see my template below:

```
\documentclass{res}‎ 
‎\newsectionwidth{0pt}  
‎\setlength{\textheight}{10.2in} 
‎\topmargin=-.5in     
‎\oddsidemargin=-.5in   

‎\begin{document}‎
‎\newdimen\boxrulethickness\newdimen\boxaroundhmargin\newdimen\boxaroundvmargin‎
‎\boxrulethickness=.5pt        
‎\boxaroundhmargin=35pt   
‎\boxaroundvmargin=40pt        

‎\hsize=7.5in
‎\newbox\MACboxA  \newdimen\MACdimenA‎

‎\def\borderandboxit#1#2#3{\vbox{\hrule height#2\hbox{\vrule width#2\hskip#1\hskip-#2%‎
  ‎\vbox{\vskip#1\relax#3\vskip#1}\hskip#1\hskip-#2\vrule width#2}\hrule height#2}}‎
%
‎\long\def\boxaround#1{\vskip6pt‎
  ‎{\MACdimenA=\hsize \advance\MACdimenA by-\boxaroundhmargin‎
   ‎\advance\MACdimenA by-\boxaroundhmargin  
   ‎\setbox\MACboxA=\hbox to \hsize{\hskip\boxaroundhmargin
                     ‎\vbox{\hsize=\MACdimenA‎
                           ‎\vskip\boxaroundvmargin #1‎
                           ‎\vskip\boxaroundvmargin}\hss}%‎
   ‎\borderandboxit{0pt}\boxrulethickness{\box\MACboxA}}%‎
  ‎\vskip2pt plus0pt minus0pt‎
}


‎\boxaround{ 

‎\name{MATTHEW M‎. ‎PARKER\\[12pt]}‎
‎\address{\bf Present Address\\2174 Seventh Street\\Troy‎, ‎NY 12180\\‎
        ‎(518) 272-4460}‎ 
‎\address{\bf Permanent Address\\241 Park Avenue\\‎
         ‎New York‎, ‎NY 01810\\ (212) 742-4937}‎


‎\begin{resume}‎

‎\section{\sl  Objective}  

‎A  summer  position  in the field of Mechanical Engineering‎, ‎with‎ 
‎emphasis on Automation/Robotics‎ 

‎\section{\sl  Education}‎
‎Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute‎, ‎B.S.‎,  ‎Mechanical  Engineering‎, 
‎expected December 1990‎ 

‎Bronx High School of Science‎, ‎Graduated with Honors‎, ‎June 1987‎ 

‎\section{\sl  Related Experience}‎
‎\begin{ncolumn}{2}‎
‎{\it Student Production Engineer}  &   5/89-12/89‎ 
‎\end{ncolumn}\\‎
‎RCA‎ - ‎Missile and Surface Radar Division‎, ‎Moorestown‎, ‎NJ \\‎
‎Involved  in  prototyping  and design of a vision guided robotics‎ 
‎workcell‎. ‎Generated robotic workcell equipment planning diagrams‎, 
‎software  specifications‎, ‎and integration schematics‎. ‎Using a CAD‎ 
‎system‎,  ‎designed  end-effectors‎,  ‎fixtures‎,  ‎and  parts   trays‎. 
‎Developed  communication  protocols between the vision system and‎ 
‎the robots‎, ‎and  prototyped  software  to  control  the  assembly‎ 
‎process of the workcell‎, ‎which in its entirety includes 2 robots‎, 
‎vision  system‎,  ‎conveyor  system‎,  ‎tray  feeders‎,  ‎and   various‎ 
‎sensors‎. 

‎\begin{ncolumn}{2}‎ 
‎{\it Industrial Engineering Trainee} &  5/88-8/88‎ 
‎\end{ncolumn}\\‎
‎Mattel Toys‎, ‎Hawthorne‎, ‎CA \\‎
‎Analyzed  the  computing  needs  of  the  Industrial  Engineering‎ 
‎department‎,  ‎interviewed  prospective  vendors‎,  ‎evaluated  their‎ 
‎computer  hardware  and  software  products‎,  ‎and recommended the‎ 
‎system  that  best  met  the  department's   requirements‎.   ‎Also‎ 
‎developed  a software program to graphically systemize production‎ 
‎line flow charts and trained engineers and technicians to use the‎ 
‎various software‎. 

‎\begin{ncolumn}{2}‎
‎{\it Structural Engineering Trainee} & 5/87-8/87‎
‎\end{ncolumn}\\‎  
‎S.L.N‎. ‎\& Associates‎, ‎New York‎, ‎NY \\‎
‎Developed  user  friendly  software  programs  to  perform  Slope‎ 
‎Stability Analysis and  Retaining  Wall  Stability  Analysis  and‎ 
‎performed   on-site  inspections  to  monitor  the  stability  of‎ 
‎retaining walls‎. 

‎\section{\sl  Other Experience}‎
‎Pool Attendant‎, ‎Bronx  High  School  of  Science  Swimming  Pool‎, 
‎1985-87‎ 

‎\section{\sl  Honors}‎
‎Dean's List of Distinguished Students \\‎
‎National Honor Society‎ 

‎\section{\sl  Activities}‎
‎Model United Nations Club \\‎
‎Water Polo Club \\‎
‎Rensselaer Christian Community \\‎
‎Campus Life Committee \\‎
‎Intramural Softball‎, ‎Volleyball \\‎
‎Other interests include‎: ‎Squash‎, ‎Sailing‎, ‎Cycling‎, ‎and Reading‎ 


‎\end{resume}‎

‎\vfill}

‎\end{document}‎
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: This is a lot of code. In order to help people who'll help you, could you please remove everything from the code that's _not_ related to your problem and add a little document, a so-called [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that people can copy and compile to reproduce your problem? Otherwise, your question might be in danger of being closed as _too localized_.

Answer (score 17):

I get the same same error sometimes. It usually happens after the latex compilation has failed due to an actual code error, say a missing `$` or `}`. I find that deleting the .aux, .blg, .log, .synctex and .tex.bak files from the folder where the .tex file is saved and just re-running latex  on the .tex file seems to make the problem disappear. Exact same latex code - no errors.

I don't know the source of the error or what the files I delete actually do - just empirical observation and this solution fixes it for me. I'm using WinEdt 6 and MikTex 2.8 on XP

After removing all the ? that appear when I copy and paste your code into my editor, the code you supplied works just fine.

Also you might want to consider removing all that personal information and replacing it with dummy text.

Hope this helps, Good luck.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @lockstep Thanks! I can't usually offer too much advice but I'll contribute what I can.

Comment: That did it for me!

Comment: FWIW, on overleaf, you can delete hidden .aux, .blg. &c with the dropdown arrow next to "Compile" -> "Recompile from scratch"

Answer (score 14):

The code contains the invisible "character" `U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK` in each line. Teach your editor to drop these.

Comment: thank you 
but i am not very profession in latex.is it possible if you explain more

Comment: @mitra As far as I can see, the problem is the editor, which are you using?

Comment: @ heiko 
i use TeXworks editor and also bidi teX maker