# Formatting subsections and chapters in tufte-book

Tags: sectioning, tufte

Sorry. I am new at this and it is my first time asking a question. I was reading this posting:

[how to change chapter/section style in tufte-book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83057/how-to-change-chapter-section-style-in-tufte-book)

How does one also get the subsections to change to the same colors as the sections as in the top image?

Also, how does one make the chapter have a similar style to the section headings?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) There is no need to add a signature or thanks to the post. Simply upvote answers to show your appreciation for any help.

Comment: Don't be sorry, it's a very reasonable question :) Welcome!

Comment: Thank you! I look forward to participating. This resource so far has been tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 25):

The [`tufte`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tufte) `documentclass` loads the [`titlesec`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlesec) package, so we have immediate access to all of its excellent features.

Indeed, [`tufte-common.def`](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def) contains declarations for each of `chapter`, `section` and `subsection` using the `titleformat`. We can tweak them to give us what we want- in your case, using `colorbox` to help us. A complete MWE is at the end, but here's the bit that we need for your requirements:

```
% chapter format
\titleformat{\chapter}%
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape\color{red}}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{red}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\itshape\huge\color{white}\thechapter}}}}% label
  {2pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body
```

Note that I've used `\llap` to push the number into the left margin- you can tweak the horizontal separator as you wish. The tweaks for `section` and `subsection` are very similar.

The only other subtlety is that I have used

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
```

so that we get numbers for all of the section headings (the default value is `-1` which turns all the numbers off).

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{xcolor} % for colour
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for sample text

% add numbers to chapters, sections, subsections
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

% chapter format
\titleformat{\chapter}%
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape\color{red}}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{red}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\itshape\huge\color{white}\thechapter}}}}% label
  {2pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body

% section format
\titleformat{\section}%
  {\normalfont\Large\itshape\color{orange}}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{orange}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\color{white}\thesection}}}}% label
  {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body

% subsection format
\titleformat{\subsection}%
  {\normalfont\large\itshape\color{blue}}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{blue}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\color{white}\thesubsection}}}}% label
  {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Sub section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that a bug prevents this to work in titlesec 2.10.1 (solved in 2.10.2) : see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299969/1913

Comment: How do I move the box inline with the text? @cmhughes Are you still around =)

Comment: Still here :) follow up questions are fine, but will probably be best as a new question

Comment: I had some problems with this code, @cmhughes, can you help me? When i try to put an imagine with the marginfigure environment it gives me an error, something about the margin.

Comment: Best to ask a follow up question