# titlesec: loss of section numbering with the new update (2016/03/15)

Tags: texlive, titlesec

After reinstalling TeXLive distribution (`install-tl-20160318`, Ubuntu 14.04), a issue occurs with the updated version of the `titlesec` package: the section numbering is lost.

What could it be missing? Is there a modification I have not seen?

Below is a MWE comparison of the two versions. The `prevtitlesec` package is a reinstall of the previous version (2011/12/15).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage{prevtitlesec}% 2011/12/15 version
\usepackage{titlesec}% 2016/03/15 version
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title of the first chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A test section}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

`titlesec` package 2011/12/15:

[image: titlesec2011]

`titlesec` package 2016/03/15:

[image]

Comment: fixed: [new version titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec)

Comment: Aaargh, Ubuntu 16.04 is still shipping the buggy version version 2.10.1 .

Comment: This bug is recorded as [Ubuntu bug 1574052](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-extra/+bug/1574052), in case anyone want to check its current status in this distribution

Answer (score 64, accepted):

## Update

The issue has been solved with `titlesec` version 2.10.2 (released 2016/03/21)

---

## Original answer

The bug in the new version 2.10.1 is not properly starting horizontal mode as it was done previously.

You can cure the bug by adding

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\parindent\z@}{\parindent\z@\leavevmode}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\noindent}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

after `\usepackage{titlesec}`.

Here is the “proper” code for `\ttlh@hang` (`titlesec.sty` line 746)

```
\def\ttlh@hang#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \gdef\ttl@makeline##1{\ttl@calc\hspace{#6}##1\ttl@calc\hspace{#7}}%
  \setlength\leftskip{#6}%
  \setlength\rightskip{#7}%
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \ttl@changecentercr
  \ttl@beginlongest
  #1{\ifhmode\ttl@hmode@error\fi
     \ttl@glcmds
     \parindent\z@
     \leavevmode % <------ MISSING
     \begingroup
       \ifttl@label
          \sbox\z@{#2\strut\ttl@calc\hspace{#3}}%
          \hangindent\wd\z@
          \box\z@ % \noindent was redundant
       \fi
       #4{#8}%
       \kern\z@\strut\@@par
     \endgroup
     \nobreak\ttl@midlongest#5\@@par}%
  \ttl@endlongest}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the patch and your instrutive explanations.

Comment: Thanks for the code! This was driving me crazy after I've updated my installation. I've just mailed the developer regarding this issue. Hope it will be fixed in an upcoming update.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This question has been around since a week yet today I updated my TeX installation and ran into the same problem, and the report is due tomorrow! Although this one is the cure, it's a bit overkill to me :) For a temporal solution, I'll build the final output on another PC which has the old set of packages :)

Comment: @JimRaynor Just the first five lines are necessary; the rest is the complete macro definition, but the patch is easier.

Comment: @JimRaynor fixed: [new version titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec)

Comment: Thanks for the code. I found out by incremental search from examples in package documentation that adding the `[block]` option in e.g. `\titleformat{\subsection}[block]` cured the problem. Can it be considered a valid workaround or may it have undesirable side-effects?

Comment: Thanks. This helped a friend of mine this week. He is using the Clean Thesis template.

Comment: Great! I had to use the "proper" code and not just the `\patchcmd` version with the help of `etoolbox`.

Answer (score 46):

**For Ubuntu 16.04 with texlive:**

`sudo wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.sty -O /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty`

**For other Linux distros:**

First run `locate /titlesec.sty` then adapt the previous code.

**Local tree for a single non-admin user:**

`mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex/titlesec/ ; wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.sty -O ~/texmf/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty`

Comment: long life to you Sir!

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe it is a better idea to put it in your personal texmf instead. The command in my case is 
`wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.sty -O ~/texmf/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty`.
You have to make sure the directory already exists.