# Plainheadsepline

Tags: header-footer, scrpage2

I have a quick question concerning the separation line to the header. I use a very weird template for my thesis, but now everything's functioning quite well.. so I guess I will stick with this template :) However, some conflicts emerge with respect to the header and the headsepline. 
This is the package I use:

```
\usepackage[automark,plainheadsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

So I have on every page this plainheadsepline, which is great, but I don't need it in the sections "acknowledgement" and "abstract". I used the code `\thispagestyle{empty}` for the title page. But I cannot use this code for the sections acknowledgement and abstract since it also deletes the page number. Here are the codes for the 2 sections:

```
%Acknowledgement
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}  
\setcounter{page}{1}   
\input{acknowledgement}
%---------------------------------------
%Abstract
\newpage
\input{abstract}
```

Can someone help me with this problem? I need to get rid of the `plainheadspline` in both sections but I still need the page number.

Comment: `KOMAoption{plainheadsepline}{no}` and `KOMAoption{plainheadsepline}{yes}` as needed. Untestet of course.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question. So I do not know if `scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, `scrbook` or another class is used.

**scrlayer-scrpage**

Note that package `scrpage2` is outdated. With its successor `scrlayer-scrpage` you can disable `plainheadsepline` using `\KOMAoptions{plainheadsepline=false}` and enable it again using `\KOMAoptions{plainheadsepline}`.

In the following example the `plainheadsepline` is disabled locally.

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage[automark,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begingroup
  \KOMAoptions{plainheadsepline=false}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \addsec{Acknowledgement}
  \Blindtext
  \clearpage
  \addsec{Abstract}
  \Blindtext
  \clearpage
\endgroup
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**scrpage2** (outdated)

With the older package `scrpage2` you can not disable `plainheadsepline`. As a workaround you can change the width of the `headsepline` to `0pt`.

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage[automark,plainheadsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begingroup
  \setheadsepline{0pt}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \addsec{Acknowledgement}
  \Blindtext
  \clearpage
  \addsec{Abstract}
  \Blindtext
  \clearpage
\endgroup
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Because of a comment here are additional examples with `article` class:

`scrlayer-scrpage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begingroup
  \KOMAoptions{plainheadsepline=false}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \section*{Acknowledgement}
  \Blindtext
  \clearpage
  \section*{Abstract}
  \Blindtext
  \clearpage
\endgroup
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

`scrpage2` (outdated)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage[automark,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begingroup
  \setheadsepline{0pt}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \section*{Acknowledgement}
  \Blindtext
  \clearpage
  \section*{Abstract}
  \Blindtext
  \clearpage
\endgroup
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: as i said, untested ;-) good answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it also work for \documentclass{article} ?

Comment: @ha.ze See my updated answer. But if you are using `\documentclass{article}`  -  are there really any pages with `\pagestyle{plain}` *and* a sepline under then page header? For pages with page style `scrheadings` option `headsepline` is enough.

Comment: That titlesec question on golatex ... titlesec fails with KOMA 3.20.2386. Is that a current bug or will this stay? Do you know something?

Comment: Not KOMA thing at all, sorry for the noise. `titlesec` is the cause. YEAH, let the reports roll in.

Comment: @Johannes_B No problem, I saw this yesterday:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299969/43317

Comment: Saw this one too, but [this example](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28405124#28405124) returns a missing number error. This will cause some trouble.

Comment: Ah, ok. But as you said at the moment it seems to be not a KOMA problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I could solve the problem. Now, another problem emerged. I have now for every section (list of figures, list of tables, etc.) the corresponding header. However, since I have created my own list of abbreviations, the header does not say list of abbreviations, but it says "Contents". Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
% define topline
\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline, markcase=Upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \ohead{\headmark}
    \automark{section}
    %\clearscrplain
    \lohead{\headmark}
    \automark{section}
    \ohead{\headmark}
    \automark{section}
    \lohead[{\headmark}]{\headmark}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}   % define page number in roman style
\setcounter{page}{1}    % start page numbering
\input{acknowledgement}

\newpage
\input{abstract}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\input{abbreviations}

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

I am aware of the fact that I'm using a very strange template, but I worked with it since the beginning. As I am not a latex expert, I really wanna keep it that way and don't want to change anything. Can someone help me to bring a header "List of abbreviations" to the corresponding section instead of "Contents"?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: `\markboth{Abbreviations}{Abbreviations}`. But this is a new question, not an answer to the question on the very top.

Comment: Wow, you're a genius. Thank you very much for your comment!! It worked!