# section numbering in 'tufte-book'

Tags: numbering, tufte

I was used to use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{...}` in order to get the numbers of a section shown. Today it seems, that this does not work anymore!? Here's my minimal example, for which I cannot get the section and subsection numbering.

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext
\section{First}
\blindtext
\subsection{First Second}
\blindtext
\section{Second}

\end{document}
```

Please, any help is appreciated...
Kind Regards,

George

Comment: I can see the section numbers -- and since `tufte` does not define `subsubsection`, `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` would be sufficient (and this is true `tocdepth` as well)

Comment: Hi, I'm using `Document Class: tufte-book 2015/06/21 v3.5.2 Tufte-book class` and I cannot see the numbers...

Comment: That's the same version I am using. There must be something in your document that is going wrong. Delete the `.aux` and `.toc` files etc. Recompile then. The example above works for me out of the box

Comment: I'm running Debian/testing with LaTeX2e `<2016/02/01>` thus a rather new basis... I#ve tried on a different system (virtual machine running a ubuntu box on 14.04 basis) and it worked, thus it seems to be related to installation/version specific stuff... arghhhh

Comment: My version is `TeXLive 2015` on Linux, daily updated, so I assume my distribution is really 'new'

Comment: This works with the current version of `titlesec`; it's probably an instance of the bug in a previous version, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/titlesec-loss-of-section-numbering-with-the-new-update-2016-03-15

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug of titlesec that has since been solved

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why it was deleted, but there is an interesting discussion on the `titlesec` package which is used in `tufte-books`, that might cause the problem... [deleted discussion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6578/deleted-post-few-minutes-ago)

However, I've tried and changed the `\titleformat`statements of `section` and others in the `tufte-common.def` file, and now everything works fine. Either there was a change in the way `titlesec`works, or this is a bug... I'm not aware|sure, but so far this is a workaround for me... at least until the next update of my LaTeX installation ;)

Here the `titleformat` I'm using now for `section`...

```
\titleformat{\subsection}%
  [hang]
  {\normalfont\large\itshape}
  {}
  {1em}
  {\hspace{-0.4pt}\large\thesubsection\hspace{0.6em}}body
  []
```