# numbering of sections in text disappears when using titlesec custom command

Tags: numbering, titlesec

I am using the package \titlesec to transform the command \paragraph into something like \subsubsubsection. However, with the MWE displayed below, the numbering of sections, subsections and subsubsections disappears from the text. How can I keep using the custom command for subsubsubsections and still have the section numbering in the text? Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}    

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents 

\chapter{mwe} 
\section{section one} 
\subsection{subsection one} 
\subsubsection{subsubsection one}
\paragraph{paragraph one}
normal text
\section{seciont two} 
\subsection{subsection one} 
\subsection{subsubsection one} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably just have to do an update of package `titlesec`. I haven't tested your code. EDIT: I did test, and i see the numbers. So a package update is very likely to solve the issue.

Comment: see  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/titlesec-loss-of-section-numbering-with-the-new-update-2016-03-15