# Problem : No section/subsection label appears in the titles

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Here is my problem : in the titles of my sections and subsections, labels don't appear, leaving titles with only text (no numbers as "1.1.", etc.). A important remark is that this problem does not occur when building my document on  another computer (at work)... I have no other problems with my document, and every other labeling (cross references for instance) works perfectly fine.

I use the texlive package.
Here is a MWE, showing all the packages I use for my document, and the corresponding output :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn,openany]{book}

% ========
% PACKAGES
% ========
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}    
\usepackage{color}   
\usepackage{empheq}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top = 2 cm, bottom = 2 cm, inner = 2 cm, outer = 2 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}  
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\usepackage{varioref}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter example}

\section{First section example}
\subsection{First subsection example}
\subsection{Second subsection example}

\section{Second section example}

\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLltt.png)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Make an update of package `titlesec`.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/titlesec-loss-of-section-numbering-with-the-new-update-2016-03-15

Comment: Please tell us which version of the `titlesec` package you use.

Answer (score 0):

Following the link of touhami in his/her comment on my above post, I tried the solution of egreg, which consists in the following five lines to add just after the `\usepackage{titlesec}` :

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\parindent\z@}{\parindent\z@\leavevmode}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\noindent}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

After that, my problem was solved. Thanks a lot touhami for your reference !