# why there is no number in my section

Tags: sectioning, numbering, lyx

I can see it in my lyx editor there is number in my section
[image]

but when I render the pdf there is no number in my section
[image]

anyone can help me?
I think there is a problem with my preamble but I don't know which one
because when I delete all my preamble the number is shown

It's seems the problem is with `\usepackage{titlesec}` 
what make me confuse is

it only happen in my computer,

when I try to render the same file in my friend's computer the number is shown

my latex preamble

```
%% \renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\chapter[#1]{\centering #1}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\definecolor{lineno}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{bcolor}{rgb}{0.98,0.98,0.98}
\definecolor{code}{rgb}{0,0.1,0.6}
\definecolor{codesty}{rgb}{0.7,0.1,0.1}
\definecolor{commandsty}{rgb}{0.1,0.5,0.0}
\definecolor{keywordsty}{rgb}{0.4,0.0,0.4}
\definecolor{stringsty}{rgb}{1.0,0.5,0.0}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Chapter  \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}{}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
\fancyhf{} % remove everything
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash]{caption}
```

Comment: I think the problem is related with this one, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/titlesec-loss-of-section-numbering-with-the-new-update-2016-03-15.

Comment: If that is the case, you don't load `titlesec` package, unless you need to modify you sections. Which is your document class? Did you try to change it?

Comment: @Yorgos my class is book standard class? is that wrong?

Comment: no i don't think so... but try article or koma-script book to see if there is a difference

Comment: You  may have the version of `titlesec` with that bug (which explains why it works at your friends computer). Try updating the package -- see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution for instructions on updating.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks bro now I upgrading my whole texlive to 2016 versions my answers also already updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a bug from the titlesec/tex-live itself

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-extra/+bug/1574052

this is happen because I upgrade my ubuntu distributions to 16.04,

upgrading lyx using the stable ppa doesn't fix it
https://launchpad.net/~lyx-devel/+archive/ubuntu/release

**one of the workaround** is adding this in preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\parindent\z@}{\parindent\z@\leavevmode}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\noindent}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

**another workaround** is upgrade your whole texlive version to 2016 version, default ubuntu repository only have 2015 version, so you need to add this PPA https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2016

or do manual install https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: The LyX version has nothing whatsoever to do with this bug, it is `titlesec` that is the problem.