# Section numbering doesn't appear in the sections?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

l'm writing an article. In the table of contents the numbering appears as follow :

> 1. Section one ............ page 4

But in page four I don't find "1. Section one" but "Section one" not preceded by "1." how do I circumvent that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Title Page
\title{}
\author{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

hi
\end{abstract}
\section{General Introduction}

\section{Search engine}
\subsection{ok}
\subsection{conclusion} 



\end{document}
```

Comment: Without some code hard so say. Please provide a MWE, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/3929

Comment: Only a guess: Maybe it is the `titlesec` version problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299969

Comment: The code presented does not show the said problem. Also, `report` class has, by default, `\chapter` document division. If you wish to have only `\section`s use the `article` class (or other compatible one) or change the default behavior or `report`.

Comment: @johnsonsmith are you and ahmed the same person?

Comment: I've voted to close as unclear. If updating `titlesec` didn't help, make a proper MWE that demonstrates the problem and add it to the question.