# titlesec: How to get current chapter number when using [hang]

Tags: titlesec

I'm using the `titlesec` package so my chapter heading looks like:

**1. METHODOLOGY**

According to this package documentation, I must use `[hang]` to get the chapter number and title in the same line. However, I cannot get the number to appear (only the chapter label is displayed).

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries\huge\uppercase}{\thechapter. }{15pt}{}

\begin{document}

 \chapter{Methodology}
 \lipsum[2]

 \chapter{Results}

 \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a compilable document, not such fragments only!

Comment: You also can use the `[block]` style. This is not exactly the same if the chapter title spreads over several lines. That said, `\thechapter` in your code yields the chapter number.

Comment: Where does `\justifyheading` come from?

Comment: Because I'm using the following command to right-aligned: \newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}

Comment: `\uppercase` is always wrong; in that position it's very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong, apart from `\uppercase` that should never be used.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\huge\raggedright}
  {\thechapter. }
  {15pt}
  {\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

 \chapter{Methodology}
 \lipsum[2]

 \chapter{Results}

 \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't get the chapter number, you probably have an outdated version of `titlesec`, see [titlesec: loss of section numbering with the new update (2016/03/15)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/titlesec-loss-of-section-numbering-with-the-new-update-2016-03-15)

Answer (score 0):

@Bernard gave me the answer: by changing `[hang]` to `[block]`, `\thechapter` worked!