# Numbering is not displayed for subsections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am extremely new to latex and I have to submit a project report in my college. The college has provided us with a template which we have to use for generating the report. It contains too many packages and other things which I am not familiar with. As I a extremely short on time, I need some help to fix the subsection numbering issue.

The packages included are:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\hoffset = 8.9436619718309859154929577464789pt
%\voffset = 13.028169014084507042253521126761pt
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[CE]{Pune Institute of Computer Technology, Department of Computer Engineering 2016-17}
  \fancyfoot[RE]{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\footskip = 0.625in
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Annexure}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
....
```

after some pages of acknowledgments and abstract, this comes

```
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures 
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\fontsize{16}{15}\filcenter}
{\vspace*{\fill}
 \bfseries\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}
{1pc}
{\bfseries\LARGE\MakeUppercase}
[\thispagestyle{empty}\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]

....
```

Then comes first chapter

```
\setlength{\parindent}{11mm}
\chapter{Synopsis}
\section{Project Title}
 blah blah blah...
\section{ Project Option }
blah blah blah...
```

The PDF output that I see is (I use TexStudio in ubuntu 16.04)
[image: The subsection numbering is not displayed]

The numbering is correctly displayed in the table of contents but it is not displayed in the chapters.
I have uploaded all the info I felt that will be necessary to understand the problem. If you want anymore info, please feel free to ask for it. Thank you.

Comment: Combining your posted code into a single document and compiling that gives section numbers, so the problem is to do with something you have not posted.  As a new user, I would strongly recommend that you start with a standard document and add settings as needed.  Using other people's preambles is usually substantially more work.

Comment: Which `titlesec` version do you use? Maybe you have the same issue as http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299969/43317

Comment: @AndrewSwann Though it does not work in my texstudio, it works in online Latex editors like sharelatex

Comment: @esdd Yes, the problem was with `tilesec` version. I didn't notice its version. But now I have updated it (as given in the answer below).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you chaning the `\hoffset` with precision on an atom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by 'esdd' in the comment section of the question, the issue was with `titlesec` package version. Though I haven't noticed the earlier version number, I have updated it to the latest. As I use Ubuntu I did

```
sudo wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.sty -O /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry. Edited