# Section number is not appearing in final output

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am writing some thesis work using LaTeX, its template is working properly but there is no section number label in each chapter of pdf output. Where is the problem?

Some header part is given below:

```
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Thesis.tex -- MAIN FILE (the one that you compile with LaTeX)
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

% Set up the document
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{uet_thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
%\graphicspath{{Figures/}}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics to be in PDF format)

% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography

\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments

%\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths

\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{natbib}


\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  % Colours hyperlinks in blue, but this can be distracting if there are many links.

% remove the unnecessary spacing before and after the headings/subheadings
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}

\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
%\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
%\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
%\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering

% Set up the Title Page
```

class is basically a template provided by our department. YOu can view it from [here](https://pastebin.com/WjhPzXki)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code complete and compilable, adding `\documentclass{...}`, the code to recreate your problem, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: For a start: put a percent sign directly before \frontmatter.

Comment: It could not solve the problem

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use. Incidentally, why is the `natbib` package loaded twice?

Comment: I have updated question.

Comment: I am facing another problem that hyper links are not appearing in order in pdf output. Any idea

Comment: Which version of `titlesec` do you use? Maybe you have this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299969/43317