# Sections numbers do not appear in document and ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters, koma-script

Hej, I'm beginner with latex and I have a problem with chapters, sections and subsections numbers. They do not appear neither in my document nor in ToC. However, everything works fine for numbers of subsubsections...

3rd attempt:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt,twoside]{scrartcl}   

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}  
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{5mm}     
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{5mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter                           
\def\printtitle                     
\makeatother                                        
\def\chapter{\flushleft\LARGE\textbf}
\def\section{}
\def\subsection{\flushleft\textbf{}}
\def\justify{}
\def\linestretch{}

\begin{document}
\title{}    
\printtitle                 
\printauthor                

\include{chapter2}

\end{document}

\chapter{
\flushleft\textbf{\Huge Chapter 2}
\\[0.5cm]}
\linespread{1}
\normalsize
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your document runs at least two times through LaTeX? Without removing miscellaneous aux-, toc- and so on files in between? If so you should cook down your example to a minimal working example (eg there are lots of packages that have definitely nothing to do with your problem).

Comment: Please do not show us screenshots of a code snippet. Always show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Making such a MWE will help you to find the critical code and sometimes even to find a solution. Showing us such a MWE will help us to reproduce the problem, test our suggestions and find a solution. BTW: Remove option `pdftex` from loading packages. They don't need it.

Comment: Which `titlesec` version do you use? If it is 2.10.1 from 2016/03/15 then you have to update this package (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300259/43317). But note that it is not recommended to use the packages `titlesec` and `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class. There should be a way to get the desired result with KOMA-Script commands and settings. Do not change `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin` manuelly. There is `geometry` loaded in your snippet, so you can use its options to change the page margins.

Comment: I tried to make MWE but I'm not quite sure if that's what you need... 9
@esdd honestly, I don't know which version do I use. How do I find out?
But as I remember my sections had had numbers at the very beginning, then I think I modified something and they disappeared..

Comment: Please copy/paste the code so we can copy/paste and test your example. Just looking at a screenshot isn't helpful and nobody is going to type the text on a keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, but there are really strange things in your preamble. Remove all the redefinitions of  `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` etc. from your code! They remove the numbers from your document and they are all wrong and result in a misusage of the `\chapter` command. There should be no formatting commands inside the argument of a sectioning commands.

Comment: If you want to use `\chapter` then use `scrreprt` or `scrbook` instead `scrartcl`. Article classes do not know chapters.

Answer (score 4):

If you need chapters then use a report or book class like `scrreprt` or `scrbook`. Do not load `scrartcl` and define a `\chapter` command. And do not redefine `\section` and `\subsection` in that complettly wrong way. Your definitions remove the numbers for sections und subsections - amongst other strange things.

Maybe the following example could be a starting point. But I do not know which packages do you really need and how the sectioning titles should be formatted. Note that it is not recommended (and normally not necessary) to use `titlesec`, `tocloft` and `fancyhdr` together with a KOMA-Script class.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,twoside=semi,usegeometry]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage{geometry}% needed?
%\usepackage{subfiles}% needed?
%\usepackage{xstring}% needed?
%\usepackage{adjustbox}% needed?

\usepackage{blindtext} %only for dummy text in the example

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp,
  afterskip=.5cm,
  font=\Huge
]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\blindtext

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you SOOO much! 
It seems like it works for everything but chapters... I still cannot number them and if I remove \def\chapter my whole document crashes...

Comment: Did you replace `scrartcl` by `scrreprt`? Class `scrartcl` does not know chapters.

Comment: yes, I did it the same as in the code you posted

Comment: If my example itself works for you, then ask a new question with a new short MWE which reproduces the issue and link to this question here.