# titlesec does not render any section's label on my machine

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

I have this code which uses titlesec:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\huge\bfseries\lowercase}
{$\bullet$}
{0em}
{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\bfseries\Large}
{\thesubsection}
{0em}
{}

%Document begins here
\begin{document}

\title{Resume}
\author{VDK}

\maketitle

\section{Technical skills}

\subsection{Languages}

\subsubsection{Programming}
Java, C, C++

\subsubsection{Markup Languages}
HTML, LaTeX

\section{Education}
Bachelor of Information Technology

\section{General Skills}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Mental skills}
\item{Talking skills}
\item{This}
\item{That}
\item{These}
\end{itemize}

\section{Experience}
I have five years of intern (that's a little bit too much but who cares)

\end{document}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how my machine couldn't render the label and numbering of anything. BUT, what ticks me off is: when I paste the exact same code on ShareLaTex, it renders just fine!

I've looked into the log file and nothing seems to be wrong but  a minor warning. Here is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.9.9)  12 SEP 2017 17:26
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**resume.tex
(./resume.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/anyfontsize/anyfontsize.sty
Package: anyfontsize 2007/11/22 anyfontsize.sty by pts
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty
Package: titlesec 2016/03/15 v2.10.1 Sectioning titles
\ttl@box=\box26
\beforetitleunit=\skip43
\aftertitleunit=\skip44
\ttl@plus=\dimen103
\ttl@minus=\dimen104
\ttl@toksa=\toks14
\titlewidth=\dimen105
\titlewidthlast=\dimen106
\titlewidthfirst=\dimen107
) (./resume.aux)
\openout1 = `resume.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+cmr on input line 43.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd
File: omscmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 43.
 [1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] (./resume.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 531 strings out of 493029
 6549 string characters out of 6136235
 61423 words of memory out of 5000000
 4130 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 7589 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,6n,28p,122b,187s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/
share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share/
texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texliv
e/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf
-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/ty
pe1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on resume.pdf (2 pages, 67093 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 35 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 24 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

This is what it looks like when compiled on my computer:
[image: My computer's output]

And this is what it looks like when compiled on ShareLatex:
[image: ShareLaTex's output]

Also, any alternatives will be okay (for example, some other packages, or something different from LaTex, etc...). I'm just a user looking for a better solution to write reports.

Comment: your code produces a one page pdf file with headings,  can you show your log

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added the log file, please take a look.

Comment: You have a titlesec version with a bug: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/titlesec-loss-of-section-numbering-with-the-new-update-2016-03-15. You should update.

Comment: After updating your titlesec package, remove `\lowercase`, that doesn't belong there.

Comment: Alright, I updated the package and it works. First of all, I want to say thanks to Fischer and others who commented. Second of all, I want to ask if this question is too dumb and should be deleted; and what other pitfalls are there when using LaTex so I can avoid asking stupid questions like these?