# Number before section name does not appear

Tags: numbering

Why isn't there a number before the section name?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\abstractname{\normalfont\large\textsc{Abstract}}
\begin{abstract}
Some abstract
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand\contentsname{\centering\normalfont\large\textsc{Contents}}
\tableofcontents

\section{Some section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which section? [This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbeoH.png). Are you referring to the Abstract and Contents sections?

Comment: Well, that is weird. I have no 1 before the section in the output. (The last 1 in your output)

Comment: from the example as posted above or in your real document?

Comment: The example above. Well, both...

Comment: You probably need to update your tex system see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/titlesec-loss-of-section-numbering-with-the-new-update-2016-03-15/300259#300259

Comment: Is this possible with linux and an inallation via apt?

Comment: well check your version for titlesec, the linked question says you need "issue has been solved with titlesec version 2.10.2 (released 2016/03/21)" and has a workaround if you do not want to update