# Paragraph numbers with titlesec

Tags: titlesec, paragraphs

I am using `titlesec` in order to redefine `\paragraph` to appear hanging as a `\section`. Strangely (to me, at least), the paragraph numbers do not appear. This is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\S.\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{section}
\setcounter{paragraph}{1}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
This is the paragraph n.\ \theparagraph

Some text.

\end{document}
```

This is how it is compiled on my system:

[image]

Why is that paragraph number does not appear and why is its value equal to 0, notwithstanding I set the counter to `1`?

Comment: Related, although a different problem (i.e., for future visitors, but not too far into the future, because it is a fixed bug): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/titlesec-loss-of-section-numbering-with-the-new-update-2016-03-15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default counter `paragraph` is reset when counter `subsubsection` changes which is reset when counter `subsection` changes ... So you have to use `\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}`.

To get numbered `paragraph`s change counter `secnumdepth` to 4.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\S.\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
This is the paragraph n.\ \theparagraph

Some text.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]