# Change tufte-book definition file

Tags: tufte, texmf, environment-variables

I want to make a few changes to the styling of the document-class `tufte-book` - Change the headings typeface, customize section numbering, bibliography style etc.

As correctly stated in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96090/formatting-subsections-and-chapters-in-tufte-book/96125#96125), one can achieve that by changing the definitions file inside [`tufte-common.def`](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def).

I made the desired changes to this file, and explicitly refered to the changes.

**It worked perfect when the document class was tufte-*handout*, but not tufte-*book*.**

Why?

Suppose my project structure is as follows:

```
root folder
├ main.tex
├ latexmkrc
└───figures
| │ figure01
│ │ figure02
│ │ figure03
└───template
│ └───tufte
│ │ │ tufte-book.cls
│ │ │ tufte.bst
│ │ │ tufte-handout.cls
│ │ │ tufte-common.def
```

Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/how-can-i-keep-a-clean-document-folder-with-custom-cls-sty-bst-files-in-a-s/50847#50847), I created a new `latexmkrc` file that contains the following information:

```
$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./template/tufte//:' . $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'};
$ENV{'BSTINPUTS'}='./template/tufte//:' . $ENV{'BSTINPUTS'};
```

So we now search the `./template/tufte/` folder first before searching the system TEXINPUTS to locate package files.

What changes should be amended so that what I propose here works.

Comment: You don't have to change `tufte-common.def` directly, you can save your changes in a new file and load it explicitly or you can even make the changes in your document.

Comment: @DG' Thanks for the idea of making changes in a separate file, I didn't think of it.
Either way, I still would like to find a way to do that, so as to "fork" the complete document class to my project.

Comment: You can fork https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex and maintain your own version, if you really have to. In that case, you can either rename the fork and have it next to the original `tufte-latex` or you leave the name as it is and remove the original `tufte-latex` from your installation. I'd recommend the first.

Comment: I edited the original post. I hope it is clearer now.