# How to get the res class document to work for a resume?

Tags: pdftex, cv, resume

So I tried to start my resume like this:

```
\documentclass{res} 

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\cfoot{Name}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\name{Name}
\address{Address info}
```

I got the error Missing \begin{document}

I don't know why I keep getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related [LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82818/latex-error-missing-begindocument) and http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=missbegdoc. possible Workaround: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100796/15717. BTW `\end{document}` is missing in MWE code. Also Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98868/15717

Answer (score 1):

In the resume class I believe you need to `\begin{resume}` as well. Here is a MWE based on yours.

```
\documentclass{res} 

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\cfoot{Name}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\name{Name}
\address{Address info}
\begin{resume}
I worked
\end{resume}

\end{document}
```